# How to change animation duration of a class using values from JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element that has both an ID and Class - The ID has all of its actual properties, while the class exists just to remove and add the animation (for something non related to the question). However, along with the removal, I need to change to animation duration.

I can't use the simple `(element).style.animationDuration = (value)` since it accesses the ID, which doesn't have the animation. I tried creating a new variable by className, but it also doesn't work - here's what I tried:

```
let npc1Ani = document.getElementsByClassName("npc1Ani");
npc1Ani[0].style.animationDuration = "1s";
```

Still doesn't work. It tells me it can't read the property of undefined.

Comment: create a complete snippet please.

Comment: May you add a [mcve] to your question? It'd be helpful to see a demo of the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using pure js

```
document.getElementsByClassName("npc1Ani")[0].style.animationDuration = "1s";
```

When I tried this method it seems to work.